# Trigger focus in elements in angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a component as (Angular 4.1.0) -

```
<div id="create1" style="height: auto" materialize>
 <div class="input-field" style="height: auto">
   <textarea id="**create-post**" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
   <label for="create-post">Write something ...</label>
 </div>
 <div class="card-action">
  <a class="left"><i class="material-icons">**close**</i> </a>
  <a class="right">Post</a>
 </div>
```

1.So the problem is when I focus on [**create-post**] element then it should trigger the [**close**] element also, else the [**close**] element should be hidden.

the component css has this -

```
.input-field textarea:focus {
border-bottom: 1px solid #00b8d4;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #00b8d4;
**height**: 400px;}
```

2.although the **height**:400px but when the content increases of the **textarea** it should also extend its height! Contents should not become scrollable instead the **textarea** should increase its height
anyone have any idea how to attain this?

Comment: don't understand 'when the height increases it should also extend its height!', it's confusing.

Comment: added more explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the focus event in angular directly in your template and connect it to the javascript to do whatever you need to do.

```
<textarea id="**create-post**" (focus)="doWhatsNeeded()"></textarea>
```

then in your component declare the function:

```
doWhatsNeeded(){
    //do something
}
```